# Mouse hover on a DIV element not working in IE9

Tags: css, html

I am working on a pure HTML/CSS layout. I have a dive with an ID, I have the following css code:

```
#headerTitleLeft:hover
{
    background: lime;
}
```

This works with OPERA browser but not with IE9. IS there some directive to use or an alternative way?

Comment: Is your document in quirks mode?

Comment: I have this line in the beggining of html, not sure if it is quirks mode or not `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> `

Comment: @MikeL. makes a good point. If it does end up being a rendering mode issue, this may help - `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />` - http://www.alistapart.com/articles/beyonddoctype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `background-color` instead of the shorthand `background` and/or the `hexadecimal` representation of `lime`.